# Android Adapter getView null

Tags: android

When it starts run , there is no error in first 5 row and follower 3 row. But then it gives null pointer exception. I can't solve why it is happening ?

Code snippet:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    PaylasilanHolder holder;
    final int pozisyon = position;
    Object currentpaylasilan = getItem(position);
    Paylasilanlar paylasilan = (Paylasilanlar) currentpaylasilan;
    if (convertView == null) {
        Log.i("tago", "convertview null");
        holder = new PaylasilanHolder();
        if (paylasilan.cesit.equals("text")) {

            convertView = lala.inflate(R.layout.paylasilanyazi,null);
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
            holder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
            holder.image1 = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton11);
            Log.i("tago", "texttexttext");
        } else if (paylasilan.cesit.equals("teklifoto")) {

            convertView = lala.inflate(R.layout.paylasilanresim,null);
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
            holder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
            holder.image1 = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton11);
            Log.i("tago", "tekliteklitekli");
        } else if (paylasilan.cesit.equals("ikilifoto")) {
            Log.i("tago", "ikiliikiliikili");
        } else if (paylasilan.cesit.equals("anket")) {

            convertView = lala.inflate(R.layout.paylasilananket, null);
            holder.etv1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
            holder.etv2 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText6);
            holder.etv3 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText7);
            holder.etv4 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText8);
            Log.i("tago", "anketanketanket");
        }

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (PaylasilanHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (paylasilan.cesit.equals("text")) {
        holder.tv1.setText(paylasilanlarListesi.get(position).getGonderenid());
        holder.tv2.setText(paylasilanlarListesi.get(position).getYaziveyaurl());
    } else if (paylasilan.cesit.equals("teklifoto")) {
        holder.tv3.setText(paylasilanlarListesi.get(position).getGonderenid());
        new urldenResim(holder.image1).execute(paylasilanlarListesi.get(position).getYaziveyaurl());
    } else if (paylasilan.cesit.equals("ikilifoto")) {

    } else if (paylasilan.cesit.equals("anket")) {
        holder.etv1.setText(paylasilanlarListesi.get(position).getQuestion());
        holder.etv2.setText(paylasilanlarListesi.get(position).getOption1());
        holder.etv3.setText(paylasilanlarListesi.get(position).getOption2());
        holder.etv4.setText(paylasilanlarListesi.get(position).getOption3());
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

It gives :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference    

 com.example.bahadir.myapplicationn.PaylasilanlarAdapter.getView(PaylasilanlarAdapter.java:128)
```

in holder.tv3.settext() method.

How can i overcome it ?

Comment: you want to set int to String object just try holder.tv3.setText(""+paylasilanlarListesi.get(position).getGonderenid());

Comment: Gonderenid is string Mahesh :)

Comment: Could you post paylasilanresim and paylasilanyazi layouts

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix different views like that. Because if for example you have first 10 items `paylasilan.cesit.equals("anj=ket")` and after that some other items, adapter views would be already initialized with `R.layout.paylasilananket` and sure that `holder.tv3.setText` would give you `NullPointerException`

You should either mix all layouts into one layout and show/hide parts according to item which is pretty bad or use viewTypes like in this tutorial: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html

Comment: First "text" row come then three "teklifoto" row come then three "text" row come then crash !?

Comment: I've meant that it's very easy to get crash. ConvertView is kind of cached and current item could be not the same as the item when convertView was created.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using only one kind of a view holder I would think, that you're also handling one kind of view in your adapter. So you're creating a view of one type and reuse it with another.

You have to override [`getViewTypeCount()`](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) and [`getItemViewType(int position)`](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) to return the correct values for your model to work.

Comment: I override these methods in class ( sorry for didn't mention). Actually different kind of views be formed properly to the ninth row.

Comment: @CaveMan for me it still sounds like an issue with Recycling. Maybe add this code to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this as you're doing now. The crash arises when you try to reuse a cell which is of a different kind, and you're trying to get a reference to a non-existance text-field.

You have to add another field to "PaylasilanHolder" and set that to the type of cell when you inflate a new cell.

When you are reusing a cell ie: when "convertView != null", you also have to check whether the cell types are the same by referring to the new field you defined in "PaylasilanHolder". Otherwise, inflate the cell again.